# Silverstripe custom front end form is not rendering

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am learning SilverStripe and creating a custom front end file. But I cannot render the form in the view.

This is my ArticlePageController.php

```
class ArticlePageController extends PageController
{
    private static $allowed_actions = [
        'CommentForm'
    ];

    public function CommentForm()
    {
        $form = Form::create(
            $this,
            __FUNCTION__,
            FieldList::create(
                TextField::create('Name', '')->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Name*'),
                EmailField::create('Email', '')->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Email*'),
                TextareaField::create('Comment', '')->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Comment*')
            ),
            FieldList::create(
                FormAction::create('handleComment', 'Post Comment')
            ),
            RequiredFields::create('Name', 'Email', 'Comment')
        );

        return $form;
    }

    public function handleComment($data, $form)
    {
        $comment = ArticleComment::create();
        $comment->ArticlePageID = $this->ID;
        $form->saveInfo($comment);
        $comment->write();

        $form->sessionMessage('Thanks for your comment!', 'good');

        return $this->redirectBack();
    }
}
```

I added this in the ArticlePage.php

```
private static $has_many = [
        'Comments' => ArticleComment::class,
    ];
```

This is the ArticleComment.php

```
class ArticleComment extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'Name' => 'Varchar',
        'Email' => 'Varchar',
        'Comment' => 'Text'
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
        'ArticlePage' => ArticlePage::class,
    ];
}
```

In the ArticlePage.ss, I try to render the form as follow.

```
<h1>Post Your Comment</h1>
<div>
$ContactForm
</div>
```

It is not rendering the form. How can I render the form?

Comment: In your ArticlePage.ss you are calling $ContactForm,  but in your controller it is named CommentForm, so you should be calling that - that might be the issue...

Comment: @ifusion you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ArticlePage.ss` you are calling `$ContactForm`, but in your controller it is named `CommentForm`, so you should be calling that - that might be the issue...

Comment: Thanks ifusion. I did not notice that. Cheers.